# Problemas con angular 4 y spring boot

Tags: angular

Haciendo una aplicación con MySql, spring boot y angular 4, he implmentado los servicios de guardar, modificar y eliminar, ahora he estado trabajando para hacer el de contar las filas de la tabla. Mi servicio injectable en angular es el siguiente:

```
 public countUsers(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/CountUsers")
                  .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

Y en el componente lo llamo de la siguiente forma:

```
public countUsersFromService():void {
        this.userService.countUsers().subscribe(val =>{
          console.log("LA consola dice: " +val);
        });
  }
```

Aunque ya he usado la anotación:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
```

en el controlador, sigo teniendo el mensaje de error...

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/CountUsers' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Pero solo para el recién implementado método CountUsers, que valga decir ya he probado con postman y funciona correctamente. Realmente no se que más hacer, agradecería cualquier ayuda.
Gracias de antemano..

Answer (score 0):

Es tu navegador quien está bloqueando el acceso, debido a la [Política Same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_politica), ya que estás intentando acceder a `http://localhost:8080`, que es un dominio diferente a `http://localhost:4200`.

Hay varias soluciones para esto, por ejemplo usar un proxy. Una solución rápida es lo que se explica [en este post](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/): usar Chrome con la política Same-origin desactivada. Para Windows, los pasos son:

- Click derecho en el escritorio, nuevo -> Acceso directo.
- En la ubicación del elemento, pon: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --disable-gpu --user-data-dir=~/chromeTemp` (quizás lo tengas que cambiar si tu Chrome está instalado en otro sitio).
- A la hora de usarlo, es posible que lo tengas que abrir como administrador.

> Advertencia: por seguridad, usa este acceso directo solo para desarrollar tu
>   aplicación, ya que el flag `--disable-web-security` hace al navegador más vulnerable a diferentes tipos de ataques.

Comment: Hola. Pude solucionar esa parte pero aun no logro recuperar en angular el valor que me devuelve el servicio de spring, al parecer es un problema con los Observables. Quedo atento a cualquier sugerencia..

Comment: No veo nada mal en tu código. Quizás puedes abrir una nueva pregunta si sigues atascado y proporcionar más información, por ejemplo capturas de lo que ves en la pestaña 'network' de Chrome. Si te sirvió la respuesta te agradecería que la marcaras como solución aceptada.

Comment: Modifiqué el servicio de la siguiente forma: 
 public countUsers(): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/countUsers");
  } Y en mi componente:                                                                  public countUsersFromService(): void {
          var num;
            this.userService.countUsers().subscribe( result => {
            console.log("consola: " + result.data)
         }
        )
  } Pero result.data lo imprime como undefined, es decir, no está capturando el valor del número de registros de la tabla, que es lo que necesito.